# Angular - mat-field gets validated without touching it

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following field:

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>ABC</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="xyz">            
        <mat-error 
            // form.controls['xyz'].dirty &&  
            form.controls['xyz'].errors?.required">
            <span>Show error</span>
    </mat-form-field>
```

I also have a button:

```
    <button type="file" mat-stroked-button><span>Cancel</span>
    </button>
```

When I click on the button the error validation is triggered and an error is shown. If I uncomment "dirty" line then that is not happening. Why would form validation is triggered if I haven't touched the field yet?

Thanks for help.

Comment: <button> default action is `submit`, and validation will be executed on submit event. Also validation will be executed on every value change. Place console.log inside custom validator and see how often validation is executed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, but are your elements in a `<form>` tag?

One of the reasons, I would expect this to happen, is that you haven't defined the "type" property for your button.

What happens if you define `type="button"`? Does it behave differently?

link:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't too spcific. My button type is "file". Updated my code.

Comment: One solution is to place your button outside the element that holds the formGroup. 

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e44ypn

Comment: Yeah, that might be a good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known 'issue' in Angular.

You can mark the form as **Pristine** and disable the input until is touched.

```
// In component.ts file
form.markAsPristine();

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>ABC</mat-label>
  <input matInput [disabled]="form.pristine" formControlName="xyz">  // add disabled          
   <mat-error 
    // form.controls['xyz'].dirty &&  
    form.controls['xyz'].errors?.required">
   <span>Show error</span>
</mat-form-field>
```

For more info https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl

Comment: How woud it get enabled if it's disabled?

Comment: Please check this stackblitz it will be a bit clearer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ifhbk?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: As I updated my inital code my button type is file. Sorry for confusion.